# Why split and splitlines not working for newline?

Tags: python

I have a variable with ip addresses in it separated with a newlines -

```
>>> print(db_ip_addresses)
10.160.6.133\n10.160.7.164\n10.160.4.116\n10.160.5.173\n10.160.5.176\n10.160.6.162\n10.160.6.39\n10.160.4.6\n
```

I want to create an array from it. From what I have investigated I should be able to use split("\n") or splitlines() on it. When I try with of these methods I get the following -

```
>>> db_ip_addresses.split("\n")
['10.160.6.133\\n10.160.7.164\\n10.160.4.116\\n10.160.5.173\\n10.160.5.176\\n10.160.6.162\\n10.160.6.39\\n10.160.4.6\\n']
```

and

```
>>> db_ip_addresses.splitlines()
['10.160.6.133\\n10.160.7.164\\n10.160.4.116\\n10.160.5.173\\n10.160.5.176\\n10.160.6.162\\n10.160.6.39\\n10.160.4.6\\n']
```

This is what I want  -

```
['10.160.6.133','10.160.7.164','10.160.4.116','10.160.5.173','10.160.5.176','10.160.6.162','10.160.6.39','10.160.4.6']
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: It doesn't contain newlines. It contains backslash n. If it contained newlines, then when you printed it, it wouldn't be all on the same line. If you want to split on backslash n, it's `split("\\n")`

Comment: That was it - Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't contain newlines. It contains backslash n. If it contained newlines, then when you printed it, it wouldn't be all on the same line.

If you want to split on backslash n, you could use:

```
db_ip_addresses.split("\\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list you need to do this:

```py
db_ip_addresses = ['10.160.6.133\\n10.160.7.164\\n10.160.4.116\\n10.160.5.173\\n10.160.5.176\\n10.160.6.162\\n10.160.6.39\\n10.160.4.6\\n']

l1 = [elmt.split("\\n") for elmt in db_ip_addresses ]

#remove last element
l1 = l1[-1]
```

output:

```
['10.160.6.133',
 '10.160.7.164',
 '10.160.4.116',
 '10.160.5.173',
 '10.160.5.176',
 '10.160.6.162',
 '10.160.6.39',
 '10.160.4.6']
```